# enqueue_scripts() in child theme doesn't work

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I'm trying to enqueue my "scripts.js" located at the root folder of my child theme. I don't understand why the following code (located in "functions.php") doesn't work:

```
function enqueue_scripts() {
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
    $scriptsrc = bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/scripts.js'; 
        wp_register_script( 'scripts', $scriptsrc );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'scripts' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts' );
```

Comment: Are other enqueues working? `scripts` seems a little generic for handle, might something else be colliding with it?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, your problem (as already pointed out) is that you are using a function that `echo`s instead of `return`s your path. However, the use of `bloginfo`/`get_bloginfo` to retrieve theme directory paths is long since discouraged.

> - '**stylesheet_url'** - Displays the primary CSS (usually
>     *style.css*) file URL of the active theme. Consider echoing  get_stylesheet_uri() instead.
> - '**stylesheet_directory'** - Displays the stylesheet
>     directory URL of the active theme. (Was a local path in earlier
>     WordPress versions.) Consider echoing 
>     get_stylesheet_directory_uri() instead.
> - '**template_url'** / '**template_directory'** - URL of the
>     active theme's directory ('template_directory' was a local path before
>     [2.6](/Version_2.6); see get_theme_root() and get_template() for hackish alternatives.)  Within child
>     themes, both get_bloginfo('template_url') and get_template() will
>     return the *parent* theme directory. Consider echoing 
>     get_template_directory_uri() instead (for the parent template
>     directory) or 
>     get_stylesheet_directory_uri() (for the child template directory).
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo

As per the Codex section just quoted, the equivalent, correct code should use [`get_template_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri):

```
function enqueue_scripts() {
  if ( ! is_admin() ) {
    $scriptsrc = get_template_directory_uri() . '/scripts.js'; 
    wp_register_script( 'scripts', $scriptsrc );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'scripts' );
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts' );
```

Note that `get_template_directory_uri()` will always return a path to the parent theme. If you wish for a child theme to be able to override this file, need [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri)

Additionally, please do not use a function name as generic as `enqueue_scripts`. That is likely to cause trouble and is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your function does not work is because you use `bloginfo` in variable assignment. The `bloginfo` function [*echoes*](https://www.php.net/echo) its value, you need to use [`get_bloginfo`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) which [*returns*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) it's value.

change:

```
$scriptsrc = bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/scripts.js';
```

to:

```
$scriptsrc = get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/scripts.js';
```

Most WordPress API functions have two versions- the ones with `get_` prepended all return their value and should be used when you are assigning that value to a variable or otherwise manipulating the result with php, and not just printing it directly to the page.